# laravel custom validator messages translation from another location

Tags: laravel

How can I load translation from other location than `resources/lang/*/validation.php` to `vendor/package/src/translation/*/validation.php`?

I have created translation file on path `vendor/package/src/translation/*/validation.php`:

```
<?php

return [

    'custom' => [
        'search_text' => [
            'string' => 'A nice message.',
            'not_regex' => 'Regex failed.',
        ],
    ],
   'attributes' => [
       'search_text' => 'Search text',
   ],
];
```

I have booted my own Validator in service provider:

```
$this->app->validator->resolver( function( $translator, $data, $rules, $messages = array(), $customAttributes = array() ) {
        return new MyValidator( $translator, $data, $rules, $messages, $customAttributes );
    } );
```

and I have created ofc the validator class. But I have no idea how i can concate validator and translation from custom location to work. The output should be overloaded by the custom file if any intersection will appear in both files.
Thanks for help. :)

Comment: Just curious, why you created translation on `vendor` path?

Comment: I'm creating a my own package. I want to have it separated from the main 'validation.php'.

Answer (score 2):

If your package contains translation files, you may use the `loadTranslationsFrom` method to inform Laravel how to load them, and should add the following to your service provider's boot method:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->loadTranslationsFrom(__DIR__.'/path/to/translations', 'name');
}
```

Package translations are referenced using the `package::file.line` syntax convention.

```
echo trans('name::file.line');
```